# Complex SQL request using join, distinct, count, and where

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have 2 tables: circuit(id_circuit, distance) and circuit_langue(id_circuit_language, #id_circuit, language, title).
I want to get the list of circuit which have more than 2 languages.

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`, `GROUP BY` and `HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3`

Comment: MySQL or Oracle? These are two different DBMS. You've tagged both.

Comment: In this case the query is the same and works the same in Oracle or MySQL database @ThorstenKettner so the tags really does not matter that much.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Then postgreSQL, SQL-Server may be added for the rest of the remaining tags too :)

Comment: "Then postgreSQL, SQL-Server may be added for the rest of the remaining tags too"  Or the MySQL and Oracle tags can be removed from this question because the query needed for this is a basic ANSI SQL which works in most (R)DBMS @BarbarosÖzhan

Comment: @RaymondNijland yeah, I think this idea is better.

Comment: The idea is to always tag SQL questions with the one DBMS used. If the problem happens to be solvable with standard SQL, fine, and if not then we know what features are available and can give an appropriate answer.

Comment: if I do a join between circuit and circuit_langue, and it's possible that some objects from circuit don't have a circuit_langue, what i have to do if I want to recuperate objects without circuit_langue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No `join` is necessary:

```
select cl.id_circuit
from circuit_langue cl
group by cl.id_circuit
having count(*) >= 3;
```

This assumes no duplicates in the table.  If there are, then you want to use `count(distinct language) >= 3`.

Comment: if I do a join between circuit and circuit_langue, and it's possible that some objects from circuit don't have a circuit_langue, what i have to do if I want to recuperate objects without circuit_langue ?

Comment: @Jeff75 . . . Your comment doesn't make sense in the context of this question.  A circuit has to have three languages at least to be returned.  Hence, you are not interested in those with no language.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `group by` with `having` like:

```
select c.id_circuit, count(cl.id_curcuit_language) as RecCount
from circuit c
inner join circuit_langue cl on c.id_circuit = cl.#id_circuit
group by c.id_circuit
having count(cl.id_curcuit_language) > 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this(oracle style):

```
select circuit.*
from circuit,
    (select id_circuit
    from circuit_langue
    group by id_circuit
    having count(*) >2 ) lang
where circuit.id_circuit = lang.id_circuit;
```

This query provides you whole rows from circuits table, so you can access any column. On the other hand, if you need only "id_circuit" column, then the answer of Gordon Linoff is the best.