# SQL request using join

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have 2 tables:
`circuit(id_circuit, distance)`
and
`circuit_langue(id_circuit_language, #id_circuit, language, title)`.

if I do a `join` between `circuit` and `circuit_langue`, and it's possible that some objects from circuit don't have a circuit_langue,

what i have to do if I want to recuperate objects without circuit_langue ?

Comment: Same question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53252448/complex-sql-request-using-join-distinct-count-and-where i see your question is basically a unanswerd comment on a accepted answer.. It's beter is you provide example data and expected results see "Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?" https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most likely did `INNER JOIN` which shows only those records that have a matching row from both sides of the join (tables  in this example).

You need a `LEFT JOIN` to view all circuits even if there is not circuit_langue row associated with it:

```
select *
from circuit c
left join circuit_langue cl on
  c.id_circuit = cl.id_circuit
```

If you only need to display records that don't have a corresponding row in langue table you could add a `WHERE` condition to above query:

```
select *
from circuit c
left join circuit_langue cl on
  c.id_circuit = cl.id_circuit
where cl.id_circuit is null
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `JOIN` (`INNER JOIN`) recovers rows that match on both tables.

If you want to recover both the objects with and without a circuit_langue associated you can use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT * FROM circuit c LEFT OUTER JOIN circuit_langue cl
ON c.id_circuit = cl.id_circuit
```

Answer (score 0):

There are four main kinds of joins :

- inner join (which is the default)
- left outer join
- right outer join
- full outer join

You've used the `INNER JOIN` which only returns the matched values in **both** tables, while you actually need a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` which returns all rows from the left table, even if there are no matches in the right table.

For reference, the left table is the first one after the `FROM` keyword.

For further knowledge:

- `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` : is exactly the opposite of `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.
- `FULL OUTER JOIN`    :returns rows when there is a match in either one of the tables.

Comment: Thank you for answering. As it is, this answer is poorly formatted, making it very hard to read and understand. Always take a look at your post in the preview section before posting. Is the code properly [marked and indented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90408/316262)? Did you use enough paragraphs and [other formatting tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)? I went ahead and edited your post to improve readability. You might want to read the article on [answer]. Well formatted answers will get you more upvotes and have a higher chance of being accepted.